# Rstudio server on google computing engine

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, rstudio-server

I am trying to access the rstudio server installed on ubuntu.  The rstudio server was installed on ubuntu preconfigured image on google compute engine (VM instance) through following commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.99.896-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-0.99.896-amd64.deb
```

I am trying to access the server through http://external-ip:8787
but I am getting error : This site can't be reached. It took too long to respond

Comment: Have you opened up the required ports on your VM? Here is some documentation about how to do it: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use R-Server you need to open the port. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/ Or in Google console navigate to

Networking -> Firewall rules.

There "Create firewall rule":

```
Name: "r-server"
Source IP range: 0.0.0.0/0
Allowed protocols and ports: tcp:8787
```

-> "Create" button. After some time (probably seconds) R-Server will be available on  http://external-ip:8787